# How to remove all the items in a dropdownList in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a referesh condition , after which the items in the drop down list of Access 2007 form gets altered.

```
For i = LBound(ddlRequestorNM) To UBound(ddlRequestorNM)
ddlRequestorNM.RemoveItem (i)
Next
```

The above code is erroring with Array out of index. I came to know that everytime , the item is deleted, the array index gets out of bounds. Some one pls help to delete all the items at once.

Comment: What kind of object is ddlThing? You could probably clear them all in one step.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the items in reverse order:

```
For i = UBound(ddlRequestorNM) To LBound(ddlRequestorNM) Step -1
```

otherwise they are re-indexed every time one is deleted, eventually trying to refer to an item that doesn't exist.

---

For a standard ComboBox you can clear all items using `ddlRequestorNM.RowSource = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply iterate the correct number of times, removing each time the 1st element :

```
For i = LBound(ddlRequestorNM) To UBound(ddlRequestorNM)
    ddlRequestorNM.RemoveItem 0
Next
```